# Is i = i + n truly the same as i += n?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading

One block of code works but the other does not. Which would make sense except the second block is the same as the first only with an operation written in shorthand. They are practically the same operation.

```
l = ['table']
i = []
```

#### Version 1

```
for n in l:
    i += n
print(i)
```

Output: `['t', 'a', 'b', 'l', 'e']`

#### Version 2

```
for n in l:
    i = i + n
print(i)
```

Output:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

---

What is causing this strange error?

Comment: No, not the same for lists. `+=` extends a list. `+` concatenates two lists into a new list.

Comment: Ideally, if you're using this idea in code, it's probably safer to use the `append()` and `extend()` methods for adding elements and concatenating lists, respectively, to avoid ambiguity like this.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

They don't have to be the same.

Using the `+` operator calls the method `__add__` while using the `+=` operator calls `__iadd__`. It is completely up to the object in question what happens when one of these methods is called.

If you use `x += y` but `x` does not provide an `__iadd__` method (or the method returns `NotImplemented`), `__add__` is used as a **fallback**, meaning that `x = x + y` happens.

In the case of lists, using `l += iterable` actually extends the list `l` with the elements of `iterable`. In your case, every character from the string (which is an iterable) is appended during the `extend` operation.

Demo 1: using `__iadd__`

```
>>> l = []
>>> l += 'table'
>>> l
['t', 'a', 'b', 'l', 'e']
```

Demo 2: using `extend` does the same

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.extend('table')
>>> l
['t', 'a', 'b', 'l', 'e']
```

Demo 3: adding a list and a string raises a `TypeError`.

```
>>> l = []
>>> l = l + 'table'
[...]
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Not using `+=` gives you the `TypeError` here because only `__iadd__` implements the extending behavior.

Demo 4: common pitfall: `+=` does not build a new list. We can confirm this by checking for equal object identities with the `is` operator.

```
>>> l = []
>>> l_ref = l # another name for l, no data is copied here
>>> l += [1, 2, 3] # uses __iadd__, mutates l in-place
>>> l is l_ref # confirm that l and l_ref are names for the same object
True
>>> l
[1, 2, 3]
>>> l_ref # mutations are seen across all names
[1, 2, 3]
```

However, the `l = l + iterable` syntax does build a new list.

```
>>> l = []
>>> l_ref = l # another name for l, no data is copied here
>>> l = l + [1, 2, 3] # uses __add__, builds new list and reassigns name l
>>> l is l_ref # confirm that l and l_ref are names for different objects
False
>>> l
[1, 2, 3]
>>> l_ref
[]
```

In some cases, this can produce subtle bugs, because `+=` **mutates** the original list, while
`l = l + iterable` builds a **new** list and **reassigns** the name `l`.

**BONUS**

[Ned Batchelder's challenge to find this in the docs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns&t=10m30s)

Answer (score 3):

If in the second case, you wrap a list around `n` to avoid errors:

```
for n in l:
    i = i + [n]
print(i)
```

you get

```
['table']
```

So they are different operations.

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

[7.2.1. Augmented assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements):

> **An augmented assignment expression like `x += 1` can be rewritten as `x = x + 1` to achieve a similar, but not exactly equal effect.** In the augmented version, x is only evaluated once. Also, when possible, the
>   actual operation is performed in-place, meaning that rather than
>   creating a new object and assigning that to the target, the old object
>   is modified instead.