# How should you pass parameters to __init__?

Tags: python, class, object, parameters, class-constructors

Coming from a C++ background, I'm a little bemused by Python's variable usage and, in particular, the creation of class objects.
Consider this code below:

```
class Cat(object):
    """My pet cat"""

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{0}, {1}".format(self.name, self.age)


class Age(object):

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.age = a

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.age)
```

With the output:

```
>>> name='milo'
>>> age =4
>>> m = Cat(name, age)
>>> print(m)
milo, 4
>>> age +=1
>>> print(m)
milo, 4

>>> name='rex'
>>> age =Age(4)
>>> rex = Cat(name, age)
>>> print(rex)
rex, 4
>>> age.age += 55
>>> print(rex)
rex, 59
```

For some reason `rex` gets older, and `milo` stays 4 years old. So if I make another cat to replace the old one:

```
>>> age.age -=55
>>> spike = Cat('spike', age )
>>> print(spike)
spike, 4
>>> print(rex)
rex, 4
```

Both `spike` and `rex` are now the same age.

How should I code the `Cat` and `Age` classes so that I don't accidentally rejuvenate the old cats?

And why is it that 'Milo' does not age by one year when doing `age +=1`?

Comment: Milo doesn't age because integers are *immutable*, and you're assigning to `age` not `m.age`. If you want to prevent the age attribute being decreased, look into *properties* to control getting and setting attribute values.

Comment: Python doesn't pass pointers around. `age` is not the same reference as `m.age`.

Comment: I thought everything was an object in Python, and that doing an in-place addition to 'age' would increament Milo's age.

Comment: @DogBreath integers have no in place addition, `x += y` defaults to `x = x + y` in the case of integers. Try your code with lists and you will see `+=` having mutating behavior. I recently wrote an answer on [+=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52747784/is-i-i-n-truly-the-same-as-i-n/52747886#52747886).

Comment: So accepting that variables referring to integers are immutable, and therefore the Milo cat gets its own independent 'self.age' variable, how should the Cat and Age classes be coded to prevent unwanted side-effects?

Comment: @DogBreath: `reference += integer`, where `reference` references an existing integer object, will *have* to just re-bind `reference` as integer objects are immutable; operations produce a new integer object. Also check out https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: @DogBreath: it is not the variable that is immutable. Variables are just references. The *object* that the variables *references* is immutable.

Comment: Also, to confuse you further, if we're being pedantic, an object could be mutable but have an `__iadd__` method (what's called when you use `+=`) that does not mutate the object but rather builds a new one.

Comment: It seems as if I should never pass objects to other class constructors without perhaps doing a shallow-copy or deep-copy. But that seems unusual , is that the pythonic way? Sorry if you've all seen this kind of question before.

Comment: @DogBreath It's quite common to make a (shallow) copy of mutable arguments to `__init__` that you want to bind to the initialized instance.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your feedback. Thanks Martijn for the link...