# Python lists being edited in place?

Tags: python

So this is happening:

```
a = [1,2]
b = a
b += [3]
print(a)

[1, 2, 3]
```

It's extremely confusing and it's screwing up my project's test suite, which takes a list of strings and tests that it gets modified in the correct ways by each function.

Did I just find a bug in Python, or is there some convoluted reason for this misbehavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: What misbehavior?  `a` and `b` are names referring to a single list.  Make a copy - `b = a.copy()` or `b = a[:]` - if you want a second list that can be modified separately.

Comment: This is not a bug nor misbehaviour. This is a fundemental principle in Python which is that variables are merely refereneces to objects and many variables can reference to the same object, which is what happens here. I think you should read some tutorials on Python variables and references

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52747784/is-i-i-n-truly-the-same-as-i-n/52747886

Comment: `+=` for lists secretly does `extend` (an inplace operation), not `lst = lst + ...`.

Comment: Ok but why? With the singular purpose to frustrate beginners?

Comment: Now I have to question every piece of python code I've ever written... Trace back every a = b, b = c, c = d, d+=1, I don't even know what's real anymore

Comment: Even passing variables as function arguments edits the variable in place in the global scope, I can't imagine one case where that wouldn't silently screw things up