# Appending varying values to loop results in list of last value only

Tags: python, list, numpy, append

I am simulating a position moving randomly and want to create a list of the position. I create a start position randomly and then add steps of random size to this start position:

```
import numpy as np

pos_range=1E-6
position=pos_range*np.random.rand(2)

steps=10
step_size=20E-9;

position_list=[]

for i in range(0,steps):
    step=step_size*np.random.rand(2)
    position+=step
    print(position)
    position_list.append(position)
```

The result of the print is

```
[6.47220682e-07 2.84186976e-07]
[6.48019947e-07 2.89315337e-07]
[6.50324286e-07 2.96818080e-07]
[6.64316483e-07 3.10052685e-07]
[6.79662022e-07 3.20408865e-07]
[6.85052985e-07 3.31529075e-07]
[6.97773479e-07 3.45764518e-07]
[7.11152822e-07 3.46809336e-07]
[7.14484731e-07 3.54165996e-07]
[7.20412104e-07 3.58339358e-07]
```

which is my desired result. But position_list only contains the same data of the last position value in all rows:

```
    position_list
array([[7.20412104e-07, 3.58339358e-07],
       [7.20412104e-07, 3.58339358e-07],
       [7.20412104e-07, 3.58339358e-07],
       [7.20412104e-07, 3.58339358e-07],
       [7.20412104e-07, 3.58339358e-07],
       [7.20412104e-07, 3.58339358e-07],
       [7.20412104e-07, 3.58339358e-07],
       [7.20412104e-07, 3.58339358e-07],
       [7.20412104e-07, 3.58339358e-07],
       [7.20412104e-07, 3.58339358e-07]])
```

I suspect it has something to with how the numpy array is stored in memory or the mixture of lists and numpy array. All the workarounds that I tried are tedious and I am interested why this code does not work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
position_list.append(position)
```

To

```
position_list.append(list(position))
```

Answer (score 0):

`position += step` modifies `position` in place. You are appending the same object to `position_list` over and over again.

We can confirm this by looking at the set of unique object ids in `position_list`.

```
>>> set(map(id, position_list))
{1637236197296}
```

There is an easy fix. Change `position += step` to `position = position + step`. This avoids calling `numpy.ndarray.__iadd__`.

Also see [Is i = i + n truly the same as i += n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52747784/is-i-i-n-truly-the-same-as-i-n)

Comment: Very interesting explanation, Thank you, But why does `position_list.append(list(position))` work then? by this logic it should still append the same object but as a list, But with this edit it works properly?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/grl7aq1Sm2xt
Screenshot as proof

Comment: @JosipJuros in that case you are appending a new list every time. Check `set(map(id, position_list))`.

Comment: Yes but that new list is a cast of that same object? Ah I see. It just saves one ID, but when append a list every time every list has its own ID, hence why it saves properly?

Comment: "Yes but that new list is a cast of that same object?" With the `position_list.append(list(position))` solution the object `position` is always the same, though its content changes during the loop. `list(position)` builds a new list from the `position` object in each iteration. The references inside the list always point to the same numbers as when it was constructed.

Comment: @JosipJuros consider `l = [1, 2, 3]; ll = list(l); l[0] = 10; print(l, ll)`.

Comment: I think I understand, Thank you very much for explaining it.

Comment: @JosipJuros and with the `position = position + step` solution you are building a new position array in each iteration and then reassign the name `position`.

Comment: It might make the code change more obvious if you write *position_list.append(position.copy())*